# Notepad ++ automate swap lines

Tags: notepad++

I want to swap to lines that start with an specific word with each other (mind you, the FULL line) automatically, using replace with regex or whatever else, here's an example on what I want to do:

- The lines are like this:

  ```
  culture = x  
  religion = x
  ```
- And I want to make them like this:

  ```
  religion = x  
  culture = x
  ```

The lines aren't adjacent... I actually meant rows I believe. Excuse me but I'm not a connoisseur of all this.

---

I guess an script would be more appropriate. Care to provide one?

Comment: Are the lines always adjacent?  What's the expectation if you have line1, line2, then line1 again?

Answer (score 0):

In Vim it can be done with

```
:s/^\(culture =.*\n\)\(\(.*\n\)*\)\(region =.*\n\)/\4\2\1/
```

In Notepad++, disable the “. matches newline” option, enable regular expressions and fill in

```
Find what: ^(culture =.*\R)((.*\R)*)(region =.*\R)
Replace with: \4\2\1
```

For details see [Notepad++ regular expressions syntax](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions).